# (NGINX) How do I run different websites on the same public ip address on different ports without a domain?

Tags: nginx

[NGINX] How do I run different websites on the same public IP address on different ports without a domain? I just want my website to be accessible by the public IP address and port. Ive done a lot of digging around but this stuff is confusing.. Every tutorial ive found online requires a domain name. Is there any way to do what I described?

(Im using Ubuntu 18.04)

P.S: Im completely new to nginx, so please explain every small detail

Comment: Why not sign up for a free domain name?

Comment: Freenom is extremely shady. @David .

Comment: I did not say a company I said a concept there are many.